# Why does specifying 'about-us' as a link target take longer than specifying 'about-us/'?

Tags: redirect

I notice that if I set the target of my links directly to the page I want to go to, as in mysite/about_us in the image below, the browser hits a 301 and does a 764ms redirect to about-us/.  If I make the link target about-us/ to begin with, there's no 301, no redirect and the page comes down immediately.

Does someone know what's happening here.  Why is it so wrong to specify the page as 'about-us' instead of as 'about-us/'?  There is no about-us directory in the file structure, so the final / here must mean something else.

Thanks for any information.

[image]

Comment: The htaccess handles the redirects and the WordPress engine manages the URL parsing.. you don't need to have a directory to have a url. Basically, WordPress analyses the URL and serves the page accordingly. The trailing slash (I think) is the standard if you don't have a trailing filetype (like .php or .html)